# I am trying to call the tableview "editActionsForRowAtIndexPath" method in a button action. the editing view is not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

You can see my code here:

```
@IBAction func edit(sender: UIButton?) {
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 1)

    self.tableView(tableVw, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to that you miss the key points of UITableView behaviour. Please consider to read official documentation first: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview

Answer (score 0):

You got it backwards, the

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
```

function is called by the table view on it's delegate while you are supposed to implement it and return an array of custom actions you want displayed - it's not supposed to be called by you to signal something to the table view.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614956-tableview